# Убрать установку top элемента при position: relative, где top блока ровно значению top + высоты всех предыдущих элементов в этом блоке

Tags: html, css

Допустим, я создам такой класс:

> 

```
.block1 {

    
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background-color: rgb(13, 5, 244);
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     
     

}
```

Потом на его основе я создам блок с тремя элементами:

```
<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "block1" style = "height: 200px; background-color: red;"  >   </div>
    <div class = "block1" style = "height: 200px;  background-color: black;">   </div>
    <div class = "block1" id = "one">   </div>
</div>
```

Теперь у блока с id "one" значение top будет ровно значению top, которое указано в классе + высоты предыдущих элементов в этом блоке.

Вопрос такой: Могу ли я отключить это? Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы я указывал top: 300px для элемента, и top было 300px, а не 300px + высоты предыдущих элементов.

Comment: Не может быть 2 одинаковых id

Comment: Может Вы хотели увидеть подобный результат? https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/mdoNvKG

Comment: Мне нужно именно вводить координаты для каждого элемента. Id я случайно добавил, когда писал ответ. Я уже удалил.